# How to add a button above Shell Tabbar?

Tags: xaml, maui

I have a shell tabbar. How is it possible to add a button to the Shell Tabbar?

```
<Shell>
    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Tab1">
            <ShellContent  />
        </Tab>
         <Tab Title="Tab2">
            <ShellContent  />
        </Tab> 
    </TabBar>
</Shell>

---------------
|   page        |
|               |
|               |
----------------
|     button    |
|tab1       tab2|
```

Comment: You could try customizing your own shell Tabbar using [Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-8.0). You may refer to [MauiShellCustomization](https://github.com/VladislavAntonyuk/MauiSamples/tree/main/MauiShellCustomization) on GitHub, which shares a sample about Adding custom action button to .NET MAUI Shell TabBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you can try to create a custom TabBar.

For this, you can refer to the [Sharpnado.Tabs](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs) from roubachof.

You can check the maui sample here: [MauiSample](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs/tree/main/MauiSample).